# How to interpret the RDB$FORMATS query result

Tags: database, firebird, firebird2.5

To get the history of a table schema changes I ran the query:

```
select CAST(SUBSTRING(f.rdb$descriptor FROM 1 FOR 32000) AS VARCHAR(32000)) log 
from rdb$formats f
join rdb$relations r on r.rdb$relation_id = f.rdb$relation_id
where r.rdb$relation_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

[Documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-formats.html) states the following:

> RDB$DESCRIPTOR | BLOB FORMAT | Stores **column names** and data attributes as BLOB, as they were at the time the format record was created

Below is the result of the query:

```
LOG                                                  TABLE FORMAT ID
-------------------------------------------------    ----------------       
4: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0       15
8: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0   
12: type=14 (DATE) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0 
16: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0  
20: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0  
24 <-- probably truncated?
-------------------------------------------------    ----------------
4: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0       16
8: type=3 (VARCHAR) length=12 sub_type=52 flags=0x0
20: type=14 (DATE) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0
24: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0
28: type=9 (LONG) length=4 sub_type=0 flags=0x0
```

There are 28 rows of events in total for the table. But I can't understand the meaning behind the numbers 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28. Okay, let's issue the following query:

```
SELECT
    RF.RDB$FIELD_POSITION,
    RF.RDB$FIELD_ID,
    F.RDB$FIELD_TYPE,
    F.RDB$FIELD_SUB_TYPE
FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS RF
JOIN RDB$FIELDS F ON (F.RDB$FIELD_NAME = RF.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE)
WHERE RF.RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY RF.RDB$FIELD_POSITION;
```

And here are the results:

[image: the results]

As you can see I have only 22 columns, neither **position** nor **id** can match the 24/28 keys from the log above.

Another finding is that there's a `type=3 (VARCHAR)` with `sub_type=52` in the log whereas 37 is the VARCHAR's code.

What is happening? How do I interpret this?

Comment: Please restrict yourself to one question per question, Arioch 'The has answered your question about the prefixes, but your question about the sub type should really be a separate question.

Comment: W.R.T. the last query, please add there `RDB$RELATIONS.RDB$FORMAT` field.

Comment: One more suggestion: try to use IBExpert's "Database Inside" - built-in parser of the FDB files. You maybe would find on the interested tables rows with different Format IDs, especially in the beginning of the table's Data Pages, where more of older rows probably remains. Then open those rows with different format IDs and check their data layouts and descriptions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I added the thing about the subtype only to reflect my surprise! See, I expected to see column names, not pointer offsets))

Comment: Ah, ok. Firebird has multiple indicators for the same type, depending on the subsystem (eg for example in other parts varchar has type id 448/449)> And the sub_type with a varchar indicates the character set (and collation, if any).

Comment: @Arioch'The probably 1. I'm using a quite old IBExpert, can't utilize the 'Database Inside' tool. 2. In IBExpert I can't see **Offset=X** field. 3. Can see readable **formats** only by querying in IBExpert. The built-in blob editor allows me to see the blob data in hex/web page panes, the latter one shows things encoded and I can't figure out which encoding it uses (tried WIN1251, UTF8 and so on). Tried reading it with php's **ibase**-functions and again can't match the encoding.What else can I do? If you think it's more appropriate to ask it in a separate post let me know.

Comment: try get latest IBExpert trial, there is also IBExpert Personal, but I don't know if it has format viewer and db inspector, probably not.  // latter one shows things encoded - they are binary data, not some text. If you want to parse them - you would have to read Firebird sources and learn how those binary data are parsed, byte after byte. Too much for you most probably, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't understand the meaning behind the numbers 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28

Those are byte pointer offsets in the unpacked memory buffer.

All your Format=15 rows have the same "length=4" column.
And that is exactly the differences between "4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24"

In Format=16 rows the lengths are 4, 12, 4, 4, 4
And those are matching the gaps between the offsets: 4, 8, 20, 24, 28

- Pointer 1 + Offset 1 = Pointer 2
- Pointer 2 + Offset 2 = Pointer 3
- et cetera

If you need to go low-level then read the low-level documentation:

- "API Guide" - https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/
- "Firebird Internals (Work In Progress)" - same link as above
- `c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\include\ibase.h` - dtype_XXX and related constants
- FLOSS low-level libraries parsing in-memory structures, like IB++ in C++ or UIB in Pascal. Those are parsing those types and subtypes to interprete the raw in-memory data in meaningful ways.

> `select CAST(SUBSTRING....`

Since you mentioned *IBExpert*, I suggest you to look inside `RDB$Formats.rdb$descriptor` values using its built-in BLOB viewer. Your log misses one parameter there, important for numeric fields. Below is the dump from some one table.

```
Type=16 Scale=0 Length=8 Subtype=0 Flags=0 Offset=8
Type=17 Scale=4 Length=8 Subtype=1 Flags=0 Offset=16
```

> whereas 37 is the VARCHAR's code.

Again, read the sources - ibase.h

```
   #define blr_varying             (unsigned char)37
   #define blr_varying2            (unsigned char)38
```

BLR stands for Binary Language Representation - it is internal Firebird's bytecode, its private semi-compiled "virtual machine". I sincerely do not think you really want to go THAT far into low level implementation details.

UPDATE: The "whereas 37 is the VARCHAR's code" actually is outright documented at the corresponding table description:
https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-fields.html

Comment: In general product names like IBExpert should not be code formatted.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel consider it a named constant :-D